# Rotate android drawable from xml without cutting

Tags: android, xml, layout, graphics

I have to do this in xml of an item of a recycler view (I'm using databinding and the viewholder pattern). Based on the value of the variable that is bound to the view, I need to rotate a drawable and set it as the `src` of an `ImageView`.

I've checked many options online but haven't found any, rotating the original xml drawable `45 degrees` cuts of some parts of the shape which is a curved rectangle. This results in a shape that does not match the requirements.

I need suggestions on how to get this done from inside the xml or adapter without rewriting it to use `getView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually used was to create four different vector variables based of the original with rotation info included. I then used a variable bound to the view to store the data that determines the vector drawable to display.
This solution is not good when you need a large or unknown number of possible rotations, or if the angles are calculated at runtime. However, I've not seen a way to do that from xml so you still need to do it from java/kotlin code

Answer (score 0):

Hello @staa99 try following code may it will help you.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 45,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);

anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: I needed to do this in xml, sorry for the late response and thanks for the answer. But I got it already. I created four vector drawables based off the original and which did what I wanted how I wanted it.